# Upgrading to Android studio Bumblebee canary 4 throw java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

So as the title says I've updated Android studio to the next canary version, after that all of Jetpack Compose projects throw this error after launching:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void
> androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver.onCreate(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner)"

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552735/error-migrating-to-new-jetpack-compose-version/68566669#68566669

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question after upgrading Android gradle plugin version to **7.0.0-rc01** things works normally now. so the solution is to replace

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha04")
```

With

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-rc01")
```

Also, There was a suggestion for incrementing **minSdk** to **24** but didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you implement in your code `DefaultLifecycleObserver` and not override all the interface methods. It is very important to override **ALL methods and remove `super` calls from them**.